# extract data from facebook

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, oauth

We are trying to identify behavioral analysis of users in fb.
So unlike twitter, where we have api to connect to twitter and extract data.
We will have to create an interface in facebook, obtain necessary permissions from users and then extract data.
In order to connect, we need information of specific keys like 
Consumer Key
Consumer Secret
Scope
Oauth Key
Oauth Secret
If the approach is right, kindly update on these values 
Else suggest how to proceed further.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: no clue what exactly you want to get from fb users, but you should start reading here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/

Comment: basic details such as name, email, gender, location , interests, work etc of user who liked our page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can´t get any data of users who liked your Page, you can ONLY get data of users who authorized an App. Information on how to create Apps can be found in the Facebook docs: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/v2.2

Information about what you can get from authorized Users: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/user

If you want to get statistics, use Page Insights:

`https://www.facebook.com/{your-page-id}/insights/`